# query for getting unique user Ids

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL. I have two databases, user and item (name, country, userId) .
I want to get user Ids that all items of the user belongs to country code US and CA.

*user can have multiple items.

Could someone help me with sql query? thanks!!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the entries whose country is not 'US' or 'CA' and get the users which don't exist there.

```
-- This part is for having some test data

with users_t (userid, itemid) as(
    select 'USER1', 'ITEM1' from dual union all
    select 'USER2', 'ITEM2' from dual union all
    select 'USER3', 'ITEM3' from dual),
items_t (name, country, userid) as(
    select 'NAME1', 'US', 'USER1' from dual union all
    select 'NAME2', 'ESP', 'USER1' from dual union all
    select 'NAME1', 'US', 'USER2' from dual union all
    select 'NAME1', 'CA', 'USER2' from dual union all
    select 'NAME1', 'ESP', 'USER3' from dual)

--This is the actual query

SELECT
    userid
FROM
    users_t u
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            items_t i
        WHERE
            i.userid = u.userid
            and i. country not in ('US', 'CA')
    );
```

Output:

```
USERID
------
USER2
```